# Regex filter containing word at beginning but not containing another word

Tags: python, regex

suppose i have the following string

```
GPH_EPL_GK_FIN
```

i want a regex that ill be using in python that looks for such string from a csv file (not relevant to this question) for records that start with GPH but DONT contain EPL

i know carrot `^` is used for searching at beginning

so i have something like this

```
^GPH_.*
```

i want to include the NOT contain part as well, how do i chain the regex?
i.e.

```
(^GPH_.*)(?!EPL)
```

i would like to take this a step further eventually and any records that are returned without EPL, i.e.

```
GPH_ABC_JKL_OPQ
```

to include AFTER `GPH_` the `EPL` part

i.e. desired result

```
GPH_EPL_ABC_JKL_OPQ
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your edit. Do you need those with 'EPL' after you have the others without 'EPL'?

Comment: `records that start with GPH but DONT contain EPL` Well, ah, you have to get through parsing the _records_ including any delimiter escaping and quotes. So, why say _records_ when you're focusing on field 1 of a record ?

Comment: @sln i guess i was giving an example of what one of the records looks like. we have a for loop that iterates and generates the filtering correctly and returns back records with only GPH, however, some records are also returned with those containing GPH_EPL. so basically i wanted to filter further on records that dont contain EPL as well but didnt know how to chanin the regex with such extra conditions.

Comment: Then you need to infuse the filter with that mechanism. This requires the exposure of the complete filter mechanism. As it is now, it's undoable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cover both requirements:

- compose a pattern to match lines that *start with `GPH` but DONT contain `EPL`*
- insert `EPL_` part into matched line to a particular position

---

```
import re

# sample string containing lines
s = '''GPH_EPL_GK_FIN
GPH_ABC_JKL_OPQ'''

pat = re.compile(r'^(GPH_)(?!.*EPL.*)')
for line in s.splitlines():
    print(pat.sub('\\1EPL_', line))
```

The output:

```
GPH_EPL_GK_FIN
GPH_EPL_ABC_JKL_OPQ
```

Answer (score 1):

This here would do, I think:
`^GPH_(?!EPL).*`

This will return any string that start with `GPH` and does not have `EPL` after `GPH_`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing that one option would be,

```
(?<=^GPH_(?!EPL))
```

and `re.sub` with,

```
EPL_
```

#### Test

```
import re   

print(re.sub(r"(?<=^GPH_(?!EPL))", "EPL_", "GPH_ABC_JKL_OPQ"))
```

#### Output

```
GPH_EPL_ABC_JKL_OPQ
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

https://regex101.com/r/GwBsg2/2

- pattern: `^(?!^(?:[^_\n]+_)*EPL_?(?:[^_\n]+_?)*)(.*)GPH`
- substitute: `\1GPH_EPL`
- flags: `gm`